# Like button Django3 - KeyError at /nutriscore/exemple-1/ 'pk'

Tags: python, django

I hope you're well. I'm beginner with Python and I'm trying to implement a like button in blog post like this. In admin part I can see who is clicking on the like.

But I encounter two issues:

- first one: when I click on the like button, the "return" redirect me with this kind of url nutriscore/4/ or my article uses a slug (like that /nutriscore/exemple-1/. Do you have any idea?
- seconde one: when I want to display the number of like {{ total_likes }} I have this issue:
  KeyError at /nutriscore/exemple-1/ 'pk'

Models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='nutriscore_posts')
    
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

Views.py:

```
class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'

def LikeView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    post.likes.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[str(pk)]))

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post'
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        total_likes = stuff.total_likes
        context['total_likes'] = total_likes
        return context
```

urls.py

```
path('like/<int:pk>', LikeView, name="like_post"),
```

post_detail.html

```
    <form action="{% url 'like_post' post.pk %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}<button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="cherry-likes"><img src="static/img/like.png" width="30px" height="30px" class="" title=""></button></form>
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: converted my comments to an answer, to have enough space ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pk` should be `int`.You are also specifying as an int in your url but not in views.

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk )
if request.method == "POST": 
     post.likes.add(request.user)
     return redirect('post_detail', post.pk)
```

To display the  total likes of the post you need to add a `property` decorator like this

```
@property
def total_likes(self):
    return self.likes.count()
```

Now in the detail template `{{post.total_likes}}` would display the result.

There is no need to write `get_context_data` method to display the total_likes.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer :) I've done the change in my views but still the same kind of redirection (nutriscore/4/ instead of nustriscore/slug/. Did I misunderstand something? 
def LikeView(request, pk):
    #post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    #post.likes.add(request.user)
    #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[str(pk)]))
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk )
    if request.method == "POST": 
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        return redirect('post_detail', post.pk)

Comment: thank you very much for the second issue. You've solved it

Comment: If you want to use the `slug` you need to pass the slug from url as you passed pk and get the post object with slug instead of pk

Comment: is it possible to stay on the same page? 
For instance, on my index page I want to display a list of post and the possibility the like it without moving to an other page?

Comment: Yes you can do this .@Louis

Comment: I think I've found how to do it :) if someone is interested

def LikeView(request, pk):
    #post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    #post.likes.add(request.user)
    #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[str(pk)]))
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk )
    if request.method == "POST": 
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        #return redirect('post_detail', post.pk)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

Answer (score 1):

first issue:
you pass pk to the redirect which is an integer (acording to ur urls.py) to the url: `args=[str(pk)]`. If you want to redirect to an url like `/nutriscore/exemple-1` you should pass the slug instead of pk (which is the id i guess) and adjust your urls.py accordingly.

second issue:
are you sure, that post has an attribute/key that is called pk? shouldnt this be the id? like:

```
<form action="{% url 'like_post' post.id %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}<button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="cherry-likes"><img src="static/img/like.png" width="30px" height="30px" class="" title=""></button></form>
```

Comment: Thanks @sarbot for taking time to answer to my question :)